# Shared header file for multiple small functor classes?

Tags: c++, class, oop, functor

I'm a new programmer and I've run into a situation where I'm going to need to create a few (2-4) small functor classes that are closely related to one of my other classes. The primary class is called GraphicsRenderer, and it is essentially a wrapper around OpenGL, completely encapsulating all of the OpenGL API calls within a single compilation unit.. Because all of the functors will only exist to support the GraphicsRenderer class, I was considering declaring them within the GraphicsRenderer.h header file..

I know the 'rule' is to generally have only one class declaration per header file.. So where should I declare the functors..?

- Make separate .h and .cpp files for each functor class? (All of which must contain API calls..)
- Declare/define all of the functor classes in the same files as the GraphicsRenderer class? (Which keeps all of the API calls inside the same compilation units..)
- Or is this a good place for namespaces? What about nested class declaration (i.e.: declare the deleter functors within the GraphicsRenderer class declaration)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from having fewer files you don't lose much from keeping each class in a separate `.h`/`.cpp` files. I'd suggest having one class per file(s).

Having said that, you can still combine the header files into a single common header that includes all other `.h` files which would make it more convenient for the API user. Assuming your `GraphicsRenderer` is only usable with the functors, you might even include their `.h` files into the `GraphicsRenderer'h` header file.

As for the namespace, different teams have different conventions about them. I prefer using namespaces solely for preventing API conflicts - I usually keep a single namespace for a large area of cohesive APIs. I've seen other teams going as extreme as almost one namespace per class.

Answer (score 1):

If your functors are not templates, declare the interface in the .h file, like this:

File .h:

```
class GraphicsRenderer {
   void someApiCall();
   void someOtherApiCall();
};
```

File .cpp for implementation:

```
#include <GL.h>

GraphicsRenderer::SomeApiCall() {
    //Implementation goes here.
}
```

There is no problem in packaging some classes in a single header file if you are going to use them together and they are small enough. For example, stl library has a `utility` header with a collection of classes.

But keep implementation and interface as separate as possible, so don't implement inline functions, implement them in the `.cpp` file and get rid of `#include`s in the .h file as much as possible, using [forward declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration) when possible. This also improves compilation times.

The exception is when you use templates, but even if you do so, I recommend you to split files like this:

In MyFile.h file:

```
template <class T>
class MyClass {
public:
   template <class U>
   void apiCall(U u);
};

#include "MyFilePriv.h"
```

MyFilePriv.h with implementation:

```
template <class T>
template <class U>
MyClass<T>::apiCall(U u) {
   //Implementation goes here.
}
```

Even if templates are not meant to be for separate compilation, this makes it much easier to read interface files and still hides implementation details, at least for the developers.